# Keep added jquery classes after page refresh or page load

Tags: jquery

My jquery code : Please let me know how to keep class after reload page

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("#themecolors li a").click(function(){
    $("#themecolors li a").removeClass("working");
    $(this).addClass("working");
  });

  $(".default-theme").click(function() {
    $("body").removeClass();
    $("body").addClass("one");
  });
 $(".green-theme").click(function() {
    $("body").removeClass();
    $("body").addClass("green_skin");           
    });
});
```

Comment: Persist the values into `localStorage` / `sessionStorage` when they change. Read them and apply them on page load

Comment: Please let me know how  to persist the values in localStorage / sessionStorage. And how can add this code.

Comment: I highly recommend you read the documentation and discover _"how"_ yourself ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check below code. You can add class value in local storage on click. ans use that local storage on document ready.

```js
 $("#themecolors li a").click(function(){
    $("#themecolors li a").removeClass("working");
    $(this).addClass("working");
    localStorage.ClassName = "working";
  });

$(document).ready(function() {
    SetClass();
});

function SetClass() {
//before assigning class check local storage if it has any value
    $("#themecolors li a").addClass(localStorage.ClassName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your code like this

```
jQuery(window).on("load", function() {
  $("#themecolors li a").click(function(){
  $("#themecolors li a").removeClass("working");
  $(this).addClass("working");
});

$(".default-theme").click(function() {
  $("body").removeClass();
  $("body").addClass("one");
});
$(".green-theme").click(function() {
 $("body").removeClass();
 $("body").addClass("green_skin");           
 });
});
```

Comment: I want add class on click and after page reload or refresh remain add same.

Comment: You can use jQuery(window).on("load", function() { /* code */}); instead of $(document).ready(function(){ }); i also update this code please check.

Answer (score -1):

When page is reload, the JS files will be downloaded again, so you cannot save within JS the state.

You can use cookies for this. See here: [How do I set/unset a cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-a-cookie-with-jquery)